# How do I serve files from a user's selected directory in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm currently making an ASP.net MVC application. There is a page in my application that will use text files (.DXF) to display graphics. I'm wondering if it's possible for a user to specify a local path to where these files are located. eg: C:/Graphics (through a settings page which I will create) for instance. From what I'm aware of, HTMl5's file form is able to navigate and select files but I don't want to actually upload these files to the web server. I just want the user on their first time using the application to point to the directory where their graphic files are stored and the application to then serve the files from their chosen directory. Is this possible? Or is this something which I will not be able to achieve within a web application? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just to check that I understand what you mean: do you want the application to be able to load files from the user's local drive when it wants to?

Comment: "Local" to whom? The server or the user?

Comment: The application will not look for any files until the user specifies the location in which their files are stored. Once the directory is set, the application will then get a path: as in the folder and the file name (from an xml file) based on which item is chosen and it will look for that folder and file name inside the directory the local directory the user specified. I will then parse the file it returns and display it..

Comment: @itsme86 local to the user.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)?

Comment: yes. I have. But as I mentioned, I don't want to have the user upload the images. just specify which directory they are in.

Comment: You would have to have the user explicitly type a path into a text box which you would capture as a string then use that as a basis for the local file path.